# How can I unlock some rocket shaped location?

Tags: candy-box-2

So, in the map there's this thing that looks like a rocket-ish shape. I haven't unlocked it yet but I want to know what that place is?

I've unlocked the desert, the village, the tree, the hole, Hell, the castle the cave, the wishing well, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to refer to The Lighthouse.

The Lighthouse can be accessed by taking the boat from The Pier.

Answer (score -1):

Accessing the rocket-shaped building, presumably the lighthouse, is an easy feat. Simply head to the pier and take the boat to the lighthouse.

Answer (score -1):

I was playing Candy Box 2 and found another rocket-shaped building in the village. I believe it is some sort of church or monastery, and no, you cannot enter it.